# How to destroy(clean) old page instance in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with two div. Menu and body.
In menu i have a buttons that load different pages to body div.
After i have return to the same page few times their methods(`*.on (click, function)`) runs few times. So i think i should to clean my body div for destroy old instance of my page. But how i can do it correctly?

dosnt help:

```
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";

$('#body').clear();

var div = document.getElementById('body');
            while(div.firstChild){
                div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
            }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing exactly? It's not clear

Comment: Maybe you are using `turbolinks`? If so, just turn them off.